# Read s3 binary csv file python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A lambda function uploads a csv file in 'wb' mode.

Code for uploading csv file which has read from email:

```
open('/tmp/' + filename, 'wb').write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
 s3r.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/' + filename)
```

Now I want to read the file, and have below code

```
client =  boto3.client('s3')
    data = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key= key) 
    with io.TextIOWrapper(data["Body"], encoding='latin1') as text_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(text_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

But getting output as byte string like below

`\x1bdº\x9e\x8f\x90dN\x18"m': '\x00\x80\x02\x00\x000\x8f\x18\x00\x00\x00', "à¥Ç\x9eDO97*\x82~§ÈÉ¸8ÀOíc\x1c|n¦Ñ\x07ä\x04Eøÿ\x14ö\x11éºóÀB\x10ÉÀ!$}\x87íàÈé;{ìÐå[\x83îñ\x96é\x7f2þ\x06\x00\x00ÿÿ\x03\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00µU0#ô\x00\x00\x00L\x02\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x08\x02_rels/.rels ¢\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00¬\x92MOÃ0\x0c\x86ïHü\x87È÷ÕÝ\x90\x10BKwAH»!T~\x80IÜ\x0fµ\x8d£$\x1bÝ¿'\x1c\x10T\x1a\x83\x03G\x7f½~üÊÛÝ<\x8dê`

How can I get the rows? I need to change some data.

Comment: How does your Input file look?

Comment: I am reading a csv file from s3, I have added code for csv upload as well

Comment: What is `part.get_payload(decode=True)`? Where/how does it get the data?

Comment: this is reading email attachment

Comment: Based on the first byte `\x1b`, I'm going to say that the file is GZipped. You can confirm by downloading it and trying to decompress. If it is, use the `gzip` module to decompress in Python.

Comment: You know that CSV files are text, yes? So why are you creating it in binary mode? Also, your call to `upload_file` is missing both the S3 bucket name and the S3 object key. Is the posted code what you are actually running?

Comment: this is common method so text not sure, and yes same code, just removed the bucket name part